# Smarty Tags PHP isset statement

Tags: php, smarty, isset

I am using smarty tags with php and my question  / issue is regarding the !isset functionality.
To start with, here is how I create and assign my two arrays. Then I use a SMarty IF statement to compare the conditions, and if the conditions are met, either display or do not display the HTML

The first array gets created from the database, is assigned as a Smarty variable.

```
{section name=cart loop=$cart}
{/section}
```

The second array is also pulled from the database, but I am assigning this array through Smarty capture:

```
{capture name='donate' assign='donate'}
{/capture}
```

Once the arrays are assigned, here is the if statement:

```
{if $cart[cart].Program == TT && !isset($donate)}
<td>Make a difference. Donate $10.00 to the ASPCA</td>
{/if}
```

The HTML still will be displayed, even if the $donate array is not set. Appreciate any insight to point out what I may be doing wrong

Comment: Are you certain that $donate is NOT being set? Chances are it is at least being initialized, which is why the isset is failing, you could try `empty($donate)`.

Comment: positive. I performed a var_dump on the array $donate.

Comment: I think you may have isset confused, if you did `var_dump($donate)` and $donate has NOT been initialized yet, you would get a PHP notice about an undefined variable. The fact that you are not receiving this error leads me to believe that it is indeed being initialized, just with no data; try `empty($donate)`.

Comment: What are you actually doing inside the `{capture}...{/capture}` block, can you post the full code?

Comment: Have you check the first IF evaluation "$cart[cart].Program == TT" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{capture name='donate' assign='donate'}
{/capture}
{$donate|var_dump}
```

will give you

```
string(0) ""
```

since only `isset(null) === false`, you may want to change your expression to

```
{if $cart[cart].Program == TT && $donate}
```

or `!empty($donate)`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

is the `$donate` array not set or just an empty array, have you tried using `empty($donate)`?